# Why does Permgen OutOfMemeoryError occurs?

Tags: java, jvm

Till today, I knew `permgen` space has some limit and when this limit is exhausted, `OutOfMemoryError` comes, and I think this is correct because I have seen `OutOfMemoryError` Permgen space.

But [Inside the Java Virtual Machine](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm5.html) quotes,

> The size of the method area need not be fixed. As the Java application runs, the virtual machine can expand and contract the method area to fit the application's needs.

So, when JVM can expand, why the error comes? Is there any limit for expansion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Method Area` is part of larger `PermGen` or Non-Heap memory area. The `PermSize` setting fixes the maximum memory the the `PermGen` can use. Since `Method Area` is a **subpart** of `PermGen`, it can expand as needed as long as the overall `PermGen` size remains withing specified limit.

The moment, `PermGen` space requirement goes beyond the specified limit, (say because of expanding `Method Area`), `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown.

Comment: As a further clarification, you can overstretch the permgen when loading too many classes, say by loading, at runtime, classes to a custom class loader.

Comment: This is actually from personal experience. I did, though, google up the matter and found these useful links:  
 http://frankkieviet.blogspot.co.il/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html  
http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.outOfMemory  
http://plumbr.eu/blog/what-is-a-permgen-leak   
http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.co.il/2011/02/outofmemoryerror-permgen-patterns-part1.html